# Assembly execve failure -14

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, elf, system-calls

Program writes executable placed in it's second segment on disk, decrypts it(into /tmp/decbd), and executes(as it was planned)
file decbd appears on disk, and can be executed via shell, last execve call return eax=-14, and after end of the program, execution flows on data and gets segfault.
http://pastebin.com/KywXTB0X

In second segment after compilation using hexdump and dd I manually placed echo binary encrypted via openssl, and when I stopped execution right before last int 0x80 command, I've already been able to run my "echo" in decbd, using another terminal.

Comment: Learn to use a debugger.

Comment: I've already used it. And only one thing that I've get is that program goes right untill execve call, debugger can't tell me what's wrong with my arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should have narrowed it down to a minimal example. See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
2. You should comment your code if you want other people to help.
3. You should learn to use the debugger and/or other tools.

For point #1, you could have gone down to:

```
section .text
    global _start   ;must be declared for linker (ld)
_start:
    mov eax,11             ; execve syscall
    mov ebx,program        ; name of program
    mov ecx,[esp+4]        ; pointer to argument array
    mov ebp,[esp]          ; number of arguments
    lea edx,[esp+4*ebp+2]  ; pointer to environ array
    int 0x80
section .data
    program db '/bin/echo',0
```

For point #3, using the debugger you could have seen that:

- `ebx` is okay
- `ebp` is okay
- `ecx` is wrong
- `edx` is wrong

It's an easy fix. `ecx` should be loaded with the address, not the value and `edx` should be skipping 2 pointers which are 4 bytes each, so the offset should be `8` not `2`. The fixed code could look like this:

```
section .text
    global _start   ;must be declared for linker (ld)
_start:
    mov eax,11             ; execve syscall
    mov ebx,program        ; name of program
    lea ecx,[esp+4]        ; pointer to argument array
    mov ebp,[esp]          ; number of arguments
    lea edx,[esp+4*ebp+8]  ; pointer to environ array (skip argc and NULL)
    int 0x80
section .data
    program db '/bin/echo',0
```

Answer (score 1):

`man execve` says this in the "ERRORS" section with regard to return code -14 (`-EFAULT`):

```
        EFAULT filename points outside your accessible address space.
```

You passed a bad pointer to `execve()`.

Comment: How did you know that error code of EFAULT is -14? I found no information about it in "man 2 execve". If pointer is wrong, I still can't understand why becouse I've passed first argument in execve that calls openssl, exactly the same way, and it works.

Comment: `grep -w 14 /usr/include/*/errno*.h`. And nobody can shed any light on why your code fails when nobody can see the relevant parts of your code. All we can do is guess...